# Proving pointwise convergence of series of functions

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, functions, derivatives

Show that
$1/(1+x)+2x/(1+x^{2})+\cdots+mx^{m-1}/(1+x^m)+\cdots=1/(1-x)$
where $ m= 2^{n−1}$ and $−1 < x < 1$, in the sense of pointwise convergence.

I have tried to bound this by Wierestrass M-Test but haven't found one, also this test doesn't tell you about the limiting function.

Another idea could be that if we can differentiate term by term on Right hand side and then check for the convergence of the differentiated series. If it converges then, the proof is done.

But differentiating the RHS is getting clumsier because $m$ is a function of $n$ and I am not getting any conclusive result.

Please suggest me if there are easier ways to do this or even if it can be done the way I suggested, then please give an outline of proof.

Comment: What "$= 2n-1$"?

Comment: Corrected, it should be $m=2^{n-1}$

Comment: So is your series then..

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{2^{n-1} x^{2^{n-1}-1}}{1+x^{2^{n-1}}}$$

Comment: Sorry, accidentally hit enter. See my edited comment.

Comment: Is the third term $3x^2/(1+x^3)$ or $(4x^3)/(1+x^4)$?

Comment: Hint: integrating the given series (with respect to $x$) is pretty easy...

Comment: @martycohen: It is $4x^{3}/(1+x^4)$

Comment: @David: Can you please give an elaborated proof? integrating will give log function.

Comment: So your series is $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{2^{n} x^{2^{n-1}}}{1+x^{2^{n}}}$?

Comment: My series has $n-1$ terms. Just put $m=2^{n-1}$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**.  If you multiply out
$$(1+x)(1+x^2)(1+x^4)(1+x^8)\cdots\ ,$$
a "typical" term is
$$x^{a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_m}\ ,$$
where the $a_k$ are powers of $2$, with no power occurring more than once.  These expressions therefore give every $x^n$ (because every $n$ can be written as a binary expansion), and every $x^n$ only once (because the binary expansion is unique).  Therefore
$$(1+x)(1+x^2)(1+x^4)(1+x^8)\cdots=1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+\cdots=\frac1{1-x}\ .$$
Now take logs and differentiate.

Comment: Are the conditions satisfied which allow differentiation?

Comment: Not sure, but since you are only asked for pointwise convergence you can regard $x$ as fixed and work with the finite version of the product,$$(1+x)(1+x^2)(1+x^4)\cdots(1+x^{2^{m-1}})=\frac{1-x^{2^m}}{1-x}\ .$$Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

set $f_m(x) = 1+x^m$ so

$$
S(x) = \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{d}{dx} \log f_m(x) \\
= \frac{d}{dx} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\log f_m(x) \\
= \frac{d}{dx} \log \prod_{m=1}^{\infty} f_m(x) \\
= \frac{d}{dx} (-\log (1-x)) \\
= \frac1{1-x}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you advance. Let's write the series in a compact form

$$ S(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^{k-1} x^{2^{k-1}-1}}{1+x^{2^{k-1}}} \implies \int_{0}^{x}S(t)dt = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\ln\left( 1+x^{2^{k-1}}\right) = \ln\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}\left( 1+x^{2^{k-1}} \right)$$

$$\implies \int_{0}^{x}S(t)dt = \ln(1-x) \implies = S(x)=\frac{1}{1-x}.  $$

Comment: How can you interchange limits with respect to integration?

Comment: Doing this requires uniform convergence of the series, doesn't it?

Comment: @Martin: You should justify some of the steps that I did. Like interchanging the sum with the integral for instance. I assume you know about uniform convergence and related issues!

Comment: Yeah I know. I have mentioned about uniform convergence in my comment as well for interchanging limits. I just wanted to ask if you have checked for these issues. I will surely justify it for me.

Comment: I have an objection to your first step. In the first step you assume that the given series converges uniformly to $S(x)$ for each $x\in [a,b]$ where $a>-1$ and $b<1$ and then you pass on to the limits and integrate termwise (Otherwise, this operation is not valid). But how do you know that the series has a uniform convergence to $S(x)$? Apart from that everything looks okay. Please justify.